# Unable to import 'unittest'

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, collections, module

Trying to use `unittest` module for the first time, however it can't seem to import the module? I'm just practicing trying to test a simple function I created using `unittest`.

Code & Error thrown below:

```
import unittest
from name_function import get_formatted_name


class NameTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
   #tests name_function.py
   def test_first_last(self):
       formatted_name = get_formatted_name('first','last')
       self.assertEqual(formatted_name, 'First Last')

unittest.main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Documents\Scripts_H\CrashCourse\test_name_function.py", line 1, in <module>
    import unittest
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\unittest\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from .result import TestResult
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\unittest\result.py", line 5, in <module>
    import traceback
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\linecache.py", line 8, in <module>
    import functools
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: cannot import name 'namedtuple'
```

I've read in other posts about the `collections` module being an issue, but wasn't sure if this was a similar issue. As far as the Python docs stated, `unittest` should be a normal module to work with, right? Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: If you named a file `collections.py` or something like that, pick a different name.

Comment: try `import collections` and what is the value of `collections.__file__`? it should be `'~/lib/collections/__init__.py'`

Comment: user2357112 - Bingo, I had another practice script called collections.py. Why/how would this interfere with what I'm doing since no 'collections' was called? Thanks!